# How to store the selected value in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

The user can choose their gender. I need to somehow write the selected response to a variable so that I can use it later when submitting the form. How can i do this? The choice itself is implemented using pop-up buttons when passing the questionnaire:

```js
function genderNext() {
  $(".chooseGenderM").click(() => {
    document.querySelector(".chat-content-buttons-gender").style.display = "none";
    myMassange("Male");

    setTimeout(() => {
      process = true;
    }, 500);
    scrollDown();
  });
  $(".chooseGenderW").click(() => {
    document.querySelector(".chat-content-buttons-gender").style.display = "none";
    myMassange("Woman");

    setTimeout(() => {
      process = true;
    }, 500);
    scrollDown();
  });
}
```

Comment: Don't write it to a variable, as it implies you'd need to store it globally which is not good practice. Instead, when the value is needed, read it from selected control in the DOM. A radio group would work better for this, instead of buttons.

Comment: You could simply use a `select` HTML tag with options being male, female, and so on. This will be easier to do than having to rely on buttons.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is no "need to store it globally" if a closure is used

Comment: I'd argue that's still an ugly approach. I'd always rely on the state of the DOM as the single source of truth.

Comment: Yes, I know that it will be easier to use RadioButton or Select, but I already have it implemented in this way and I somehow need to use the selected value

Comment: The code was not written by me and cannot be redone, but I need to take the selected value and send it with the form

Comment: @rickray put a class on the selected item when it's clicked, then use that as a selector when you need to find which option the user chose.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan "_I'd always rely on the state of the DOM as the single source of truth_": Why is that? The tools that browsers expose for manipulation of the DOM are much more accessible than the tools for manipulating the state of the JS memory.

Comment: @jsejcksn partly for that exact reason - if the user uses devtools to mess with the UI I would want the result of any action to respect that updated state - with appropriate business logic guards in place on both the client and server side to ensure no subversion of the system is happening, of course. Also partly because the code becomes much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a property on an object variable (or directly in a mutable variable using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)) elsewhere in your program, and then reference the value when you need to submit the form:

```js
// Elsewhere, in a higher scope in your program
// that you can access "later when submitting the form":

const userData = {
  gender: "Unknown", // or initialize it as undefined, etc.
};

// In the function you showed, assign the gender to the associated property:
function genderNext () {
  $(".chooseGenderM").click(() => {
    document.querySelector(".chat-content-buttons-gender").style.display = "none";
    // Here:
    userData.gender = "Male";
    myMassange("Male");

    setTimeout(() => {
      process = true;
    }, 500);
    scrollDown();
  });
  $(".chooseGenderW").click(() => {
    document.querySelector(".chat-content-buttons-gender").style.display = "none";
    // And here:
    userData.gender = "Woman";
    myMassange("Woman");

    setTimeout(() => {
      process = true;
    }, 500);
    scrollDown();
  });
}

// "later when submitting the form", use the value however you want to. For example:
submitForm(userData.gender);
```

Alternatively, if you can't create or assign to a higher-scoped variable for some reason, then you can assign the string value to a property on an element's [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property and retrieve it later. See [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for more info.